# Factually Btrfs is it suitable for block storage usage?

Tags: storage-area-network, btrfs, block-device

It exists various storage device, file, block and object based. Some filesystem are dedicated to a kind of device. what about Btrfs ?

Here I would like to get some technical facts about Btrfs over a block storage device.
Indeed, most of cloud provider documentation use another file system. Which lead to this legitimate question.

Moreover is their for `Btrfs` some interesting mount option to apply for a block storage ?

Thanks for your highlight

Answer (score 3):

`btrfs` is very slow for rewrite-heavy workloads; moreover, it [fragments horribly](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Fragmentation) and slows down each time you create a [subvolume](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Having_many_subvolumes_can_be_very_slow) or [snapshot](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/20210121222051.GB4626@dread.disaster.area/).

I would use it only for pure fileserver duties rather then block device emulation, databases or virtual machines.